# gson null when not deserialize

Tags: java, json, gson

gson null when not deserialize

```java
public class Mode {
    @Expose(deserialize = false)
    public final List<String> list;

    public Mode(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

list only serialize not deserialize

```java
public class Entity {
    public Mode setting = new Mode(Arrays.asList("1", "2"));
}
```

add deserialization exclusion strategy:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                Expose annotation = f.getAnnotation(Expose.class);

                if (annotation == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                return !annotation.deserialize();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        }).create();
        var s = """
                {
                  "setting": {
                    "list": [
                      "1",
                      "2",
                      "3"
                    ]
                  }
                }
                                
                """;
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson(s, Entity.class).setting.getList());
```

The list field of the Mode class is null when deserialize the Entity class

Comment: Isn't that the intended behavior here? The field is annotated with `@Expose(deserialize = false)` and your exclusion strategy returns `!annotation.deserialize()`. Or are you expecting something other than `null` for the `list` field (if so, what are you expecting)?

Comment: @Marcono1234 Use the passed in value instead of the value read from the file

Comment: In that case you could maybe also try using an `InstanceCreator`, as shown [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1887#issuecomment-837223846).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect solution

```java
//Step.1 get json object
JsonObject jsonObject = gson().fromJson("", JsonObject.class);
//Step.2 get all field of the entity
for (Field configField : klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    configField.setAccessible(true);
    if (!jsonObject.has(configField.getName())) {
        continue;
    }
    //Step.3 deserialize
    Object setting = gson().fromJson(jsonObject.get(configField.getName()).toString(), configField.getType());
    //Step.3.1 get all field of the setting
    for (Field settingField : setting.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        settingField.setAccessible(true);
        if (settingField.isAnnotationPresent(Expose.class)) {
            if (!settingField.getAnnotation(Expose.class).deserialize()) {
                Field declaredField = ReflectUtil.getField(setting.getClass(), settingField.getName());
                //Step.3.2 use the value from entity to set the value of setting
                declaredField.set(setting, ReflectUtil.getFieldValue(ReflectUtil.getFieldValue(entity, configField.getName()), settingField.getName()));
            }
        }
    }
    //Step.4 use the value from step 3 to set the value of entity
    configField.set(entity, setting);
}
```